# hide floatingActionButton when scroll down and show it back when scroll up flutter

Tags: flutter

im trying to find way to **hide** the floatingActionButton when scroll down and **show** it back when scroll up

**i'm using getx**

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Wrap your `FloatingActionButton` in a `Visibility` widget. This allows you to toggle the visibility of the `FloatingActionButton` based on a boolean value

```
Visibility(
  visible: _isVisible, // boolean value that controls visibility
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
);
```

2- Then Create a `ScrollController` and attach it to a `ListView`. This allows you to listen for changes in the scroll position.

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
//...
ListView.builder(
    controller: _scrollController,
    //...
);
```

3- Use the `addListener` method on the `ScrollController` to listen for changes in the scroll position and update the visibility of the `FloatingActionButton` accordingly.

```
_scrollController.addListener(() {
  if (_scrollController.offset > _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && _isVisible) {
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = false;
    });
  } else if (_scrollController.offset <= _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent && !_isVisible) {
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make custom fab with scroll controller which is explained well in the below artile.

https://medium.com/@aakashpp/automatic-show-hide-fab-on-scroll-in-flutter-2c0abd94f3da

**Please accept the solution if solved your problem**

Comment: Try to add code in your answer, and please dont seek for acceptance of answer in the answer, If it has helped him, he'll accept, if not try to comment about the same, Please dont include that in your answer, IN BOLD.